# Looking for a way to Search Browser cookies and determine href="mailto:.." link

Tags: javascript, html, email, gmail, yahoo-mail

I, personally, *hate* system mail clients and was wondering whether there was a way to get the browser to search the cookies for Yahoo mail, Gmail, and other mail websites and *then* make the mailto: attribute based on those cookies. Any ideas?

Comment: How would knowing what (if any) web mail service someone was logged into make a jot of difference about what a `mailto:` URI would do? It opens in whatever the browser is configured to open in it. Some people have their browser to open in a webmail service. Some don't. I don't. Web mail services all have horrible user interfaces.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.

There is no way to access cookies belonging to other domains.

Comment: I also believe this is up to the user anyway, you can set mailto preferences in the browser to use Gmail/Outlook etc.